# Laravel 5.2 MultiAuth and ACL

Tags: laravel, authorization, acl

I tryed to use the [Zizaco/entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) for ACL implementation, but I don't know how to link roles and permissions with 2 accounts types (users and admins are different tables). I edited the config\entrust.php, but we have

```
 /*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Entrust role_user Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This is the role_user table used by Entrust to save assigned roles to the
| database.
|
*/
'role_user_table' => 'role_user',
```

relation only.

Could someone suggest me any solution or may be other Laravel 5.2 module?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, I've found out the solution. I tryed to use PostgreSQL with 2 different schemas (public and admin). Additionally, I use [pingpong modules](http://sky.pingpong-labs.com/docs/2.0/modules#configuration) with different namespaces.
But there is not good feature: I set 'databese.default' (default DB connection with appropriate schema) config parameter in the custom middleware script.
As a final step, need to run "entrust" migrations for separated schema.

Comment: Other idea to avoid using middleware script and Config::set .. each module (pingpong module) has a personal ModulenameServiceProvider. We can add something like `$this->mergeConfigFrom(
            __DIR__.'/../Config/auth.php', 'auth'
        );
` into the "register" function. But there is a Laravel bug with this mergeConfigFrom function. Need to fix the \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider.php script.